# Finding large difference between Omega total and omega hierarchical - what does it mean?

Tags: r, reliability

I am computing reliability for some scales using the omega function in the R package psych. For one 3-item scale, the omega hierarchical is very close to 0 (.03), but omega total is reasonable (.79). Could someone please explain what that means/why that would happen? I know it has something to do with the presence of one general factor vs. separate grouping factors, but I only have 3 items, and the Schmid Leiman Factor loadings seem to suggest that   all three items load appropriately only one factor. I do get a warning message about 0 or NA entries (see below).

here is the output:

```
Alpha:                 0.78  
G.6:                   0.71  
Omega Hierarchical:    0.03   
Omega H asymptotic:    0.04   
Omega Total            0.79 

Schmid Leiman Factor loadings greater than  0.2   

                   g  F1*   F2*   F3*   h2   u2   p2  
    mot_ident        0.66             0.47 0.53 0.05  
    mot_intrin       0.72             0.54 0.46 0.03  
    mot_integ        0.80             0.66 0.34 0.04  

With eigenvalues of:  
   g  F1*  F2*  F3*   
0.06 1.59 0.02 0.00   

general/max  0.04   max/min =   Inf  
mean percent general =  0.04    with sd =  0.01 and cv of  0.25   
Explained Common Variance of the general factor =  0.04   

The degrees of freedom are -3  and the fit is  0   
The number of observations was  456  with Chi Square =  0  with prob <  NA  
The root mean square of the residuals is  0   
The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is  NA  

Compare this with the adequacy of just a general factor and no group factors  
The degrees of freedom for just the general factor are 0  and the fit is  0.79   
The number of observations was  456  with Chi Square =  355.54  with prob <  NA  
The root mean square of the residuals is  0.52   
The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is  NA   

Measures of factor score adequacy               
                                                  g  F1*   F2* F3*  
Correlation of scores with factors             0.17 0.88  0.20   0  
Multiple R square of scores with factors       0.03 0.77  0.04   0  
Minimum correlation of factor score estimates -0.94 0.54 -0.92  -1    

 Total, General and Subset omega for each subset  
                                                 g  F1* F2* F3*  
Omega total for total scores and subscales    0.79 0.79  NA  NA  
Omega general for total scores and subscales  0.03 0.03  NA  NA  
Omega group for total scores and subscales    0.76 0.76  NA  NA  
  
Warning message:
In cov2cor(t(w) %*% r %*% w) :
  diag(.) had 0 or NA entries; non-finite result is doubtful
```

Comment: I think that this is happening because you only have three items, so the general factor is just identified.  Add a fourth item (of random numbers, if necessary) and see.

Comment: This is why it's saying things like: The degrees of freedom are -3  and the fit is  0